# Facebook Score API with Corona SDK

Tags: android, facebook, coronasdk, leaderboard

I would really like to connect Facebook SCORE API with my Android application made by using Corona SDK. Is there any tutorial/solution/explanation how to integrate FB Score API with my application coded using Corona?

At the end, I would like to get something like this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did:

1. to retrieve scores for my app from user and his friends, I used http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/request.html :

   ```
   local facebook = require "facebook"
   facebook.request(appId.."/scores")
   ```
2. to update/post the score, I used http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html :

   ```
   local params = {}
   params.body = "&score="..tostring(newScore).."&access_token="..accessTokenFromFacebookLogin
   network.request( "https://graph.facebook.com/"..facebookUserId.."/scores", "POST", networkListener, params)
   ```

I hope this helps! :)